# Filling NA values in R after a non-NA value

Tags: na, fill, panel-data

The data frame I'm working on contains the columns 'country1', 'country2', 'year' and 'pta'. Pta is '1' in the year in which the two countries formed a trade agreement and NA for all other years. The rows are all possible country dyads for all the years between 1990 and 2021.

This is an example of what a section looks like. In this example, Afghanistan and India formed a trade agreement in 2003:

```
   country1     country2    year  pta
1  Afghanistan  India       2002  NA
2  Afghanistan  India       2003  1
3  Afghanistan  India       2004  NA
4  Afghanistan  India       2005  NA
5  Afghanistan  India       2006  NA
6  Afghanistan  India       2007  NA
7  Afghanistan  India       2008  NA
8  Afghanistan  India       2009  NA
9  Afghanistan  India       2010  NA
10 Afghanistan  India       2011  NA
11 Afghanistan  India       2012  NA
12 Afghanistan  India       2013  NA
13 Afghanistan  India       2014  NA
14 Afghanistan  India       2015  NA
                 ...
20 Afghanistan  India       2021  NA
21 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1990  NA
22 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1991  NA
23 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1992  NA
24 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1993  NA
25 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1994  NA
```

My goal is for all the NAs after a '1' to be '1' also but only until 2021 for each country dyad.

Ideally it would look like this:

```
   country1     country2    year  pta
1  Afghanistan  India       2002  0
2  Afghanistan  India       2003  1
3  Afghanistan  India       2004  1
4  Afghanistan  India       2005  1
5  Afghanistan  India       2006  1
6  Afghanistan  India       2007  1
7  Afghanistan  India       2008  1
8  Afghanistan  India       2009  1
9  Afghanistan  India       2010  1
10 Afghanistan  India       2011  1
11 Afghanistan  India       2012  1
12 Afghanistan  India       2013  1
13 Afghanistan  India       2014  1
14 Afghanistan  India       2015  1
                 ...
20 Afghanistan  India       2021  1
21 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1990  0
22 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1991  0
23 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1992  0
24 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1993  0
25 Afghanistan  Indonesia   1994  0
```

The only thing I've achieved so far (I lost the code though) is replacing all NAs with '0'.